# Application crashes when exception is thrown from constructor

Tags: c++

When an exception is thrown from the class constructor, the program crashes. While running in debug mode I get the following error "Unhandled exception at 0x74A2DB18 in VirtualCtor.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000." It crashes in release mode too. I understand that this because throw does not find the exact catch handler and std::terminate() is called. But, I had the understanding that catch(...) should handle this. Can someone let me know the exact handler that I need to use with catch?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
 public: 
      MyClass() { cout << "Default Ctor" << endl;
      throw; //runtime exception.
}
 ~MyClass()
 {
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
 }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass*vpt = nullptr;
  try {
        vpt = new MyClass;
   }
  catch (...) {
        delete vpt;
        cout << "Exception"<< endl;
    }

  return    0;
 }
```

Changing code throw bad_alloc(); catches the exception and the code crashes no longer, but I need to understand what happens with just calling throw from function/constructor?

Thanks.

Comment: `throw;` without an expression is used to re-throw a currently active exception. It exhibits undefined behavior when executed outside of `catch` clause or a function called therefrom.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: The answer section can be found below. This is the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *not* throwing an exception. You're just writing `throw`, which *re-throws* an exception already thrown. In this case, there isn't one, so your program has undefined behaviour. Hence the crash.

If you want to throw something, you actually have to throw something!

```
MyClass()
{
   cout << "Default Ctor" << endl;
   throw std::runtime_exception("Testing exception handling");
}
```

Comment: I must admit I don't really understand what you expected when you wrote `throw` without providing something to, y'know, throw.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That answers my query.